# Powershell Get-ChildItem doesn't work properly on IIS directory

Tags: powershell

I was going to write up a simple alias 'iis' to invoke the IIS Manager, which is 'C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\InetMgr.exe'

```
set-alias iis "OpenIIS.ps1"
```

and in the OpenIIS.ps1 I have

```
$item = "C:\Windows\system32\inetsrv\InetMgr.exe"
invoke-item -path $item
```

This doesn't work. The error I get is "The system cannot find the file specified"

In fact, just doing a Get-ChildItem on the inetsrv won't show the InetMgr.exe (no difference with -Force switch)

```
Get-ChildItem C:\Windows\system32\inetsrv\*.exe -force
```

[image: Imgur]

Obviously I can see it in Explorer and I can launch it using cmd, but not with Powershell it seems. Also, Powershell is running as Administrator.

**What is going on?**

As a workaround I tried creating a link to the file and then invoking that link from Powershell. I now get a 'NotSpecified' Win32Exception.

I have originally used 64 bit Powershell, but get the same result on the x86 Powershell (both run as Administrator)

Answer (score 0):

Are you at the elevated PowerShell prompt? Some system files may not show up unless you use `-Force` parameter with Get-ChildItem.

Comment: Should have mentioned in the question, that's one of the first things I tried. No difference in the output

Comment: I just tried the same in my lab setup (logged in as domain admin and also another with local admin rights) and everything you have in the script there works for me.

Comment: I tried in x86 Powershell as Administrator. No luck. I tried restarting the machine as well.

Comment: what does start-process -filepath "C:\Windows\system32\inetsrv\InetMgr.exe" give you?

Comment: Same error as the invoke: 'This command cannot be run due to the error: The system cannot find the file specified."

Answer (score 0):

I think evidently the file InetMgr.exe is not there as when I do a get-childitem in the mentioned directory,it lists the "InetMgr.exe" there.

This may not be the problem with Get-ChildItem or the Alias you created but instead with ur IIS Server.